What hidden content can google accept?
I was reading articles, and if people did an accordion style page where some text is immediately shown and when people perform a certain action, more text loads on the same page and it seems google is OK with that.
I have a page where a block of text is hidden until a certain time is reached because I offer a time-limited sale that starts at a certain time.
I also have a setup where text is hidden if javascript is enabled, and where other text is hidden if the screen resolution is sane enough (over 320px wide).
However, I'm not ranking near the top of google, and I think it's because google doesn't like the way I'm hiding text.
So what kinds of hidden text are or are not acceptable with google and why?

What aren't you ranking for?  Are you searching for text that is in this hidden section, or are you searching for something else that is on the page and visible?

The content people search for would naturally be visible but other text would only be visible on certain days only to advertise a sale. that text would disappear when the sale no longer exists.

In search console, bring up a page with these types of UI elements and fetch it as Googlebot. Then take a look at the HTML and see what it can find.
You can also view the source of the page and it works about the same. Analyze what is shown and was isn't and this will give you a worst case scenario of what Google can see of your page when it goes to index.
The best thing to do would be to have the content there when it downloads the page, even though you might hide the content in accordion elements. That way, you ensure it sees it. If you see it in the source HTML, then it is probably something else you need to optimize.
I always try to avoid keeping the content dynamic where JavaScript will unhide it for the sole fact that I don't know if Google will see it.
I would also take a look at all the other signals you are sending to Google and make sure they are all cohesive (meta, headings, link text, images, etc).
